# how to get google contacts email and phone number ionic, cordova with $cordovaOauth?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, google-contacts-api

I need help in getting the google contact details  email, Phone No. in ionic, cordova with  `$cordovaOauth`.

Answer (score 1):

create google oauth api in google console api like `'1234567890-qhjnn7du9jrnhchuu66cc08i7pbuaaod.apps.googleusercontent.com'`

```
$scope.googleinvite = function() {

    $cordovaOauth.google("1234567890-qhjnn7du9jrnhchuu66cc08i7pbuaaod.apps.googleusercontent.com", ["https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"]).then(function(result) {
            console.log(result)
            var googleaccount = $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=' + result.access_token + "&alt=json&max-results=5000",
                dataType: "jsonp",
            });
            googleaccount.success(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("Error -> " + error);
        });
}
```